# Несколько .xib файлов (экранов) в iOS приложении

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Подскажите, как сделать несколько `.xib` файлов, ну то есть экранов в `iOS` приложении в `xCode`. У меня конкретных вопроса:

1. Как создать второй валидный .xib файл
2. Как привязать первый экран ко второму(чтоб например при клике по кнопке было переключение на 2 экран приложения)

P.S. Можете не описывать перетаскивание с правой кнопкой мыши, как создать - распишите пожалуйста по пунктам меню. А как привязать - достаточно строки кода, событие я сам приколдую.

Comment: Вам нужно искать примеры с UINavigationController. Это крайне непростая тема и трудно объяснить на одной ножке. И .xib файлы сами по себе не существуют. Они идут в связке с контроллером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще создать новый класс с нужным ксибом, например `SecondViewController`, и по кнопке через `UINavigationController` переходить на свой `SecondViewController`.

```
SecondViewController * secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Второй вариант - это в свой ксиб добавить `UIView` (можно разместить рядом с основной view), наполнить нужными контролами и по кнопке подгружать на свой `FirstViewController`, соответственно привязав все нужные оутлеты.

```
myUIView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height); // фрейм можно задавать по разному

[self.view addSubview:myUIView];
```

советую первый вариант:)

Comment: согласен, первый более красивый - попробую)